# Angular UI grid aggregate options without building columnOptions and getting the aggregate value

Tags: angular-ui-grid

Please refer to the plunker for two issues I am having now.

http://plnkr.co/edit/EII4lR5S7P1qUUnuaFJz?p=preview

I am creating a grid without providing column definition list. Columns are being built by default. I have a requirement to agregate on one field and I am doing so by using the registerColumnsProcessor as suggested by some one.

```
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
          gridApi.core.registerColumnsProcessor(function (columns) {
                    columns.forEach(function (column) {
                        if (column.name == 'age') {

                            column.aggregationType = uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.min;
                            //With this approach I am observing that the aggregationtext is missing from the footer.
                            //How can I get that?
                        }
                    });
                    return columns;
                }, 100);

                 //alert(gridApi.grid.columns[5].getAggregationValue()); does not work here Cannot read property 'getAggregationValue' of undefined
}
```

However the issue I am getting is the aggregateText (min, max, total) is missing from the column footer. The footer only shows the value. in case of the plunker attached it is 20.
How do I achieve this?

Another issue is I want to retrieve this aggregate value separately for some other use. Which I am not able to get it. I have added a button in the poluker example and from that I am able to retrieve it but I dont want any button action.

```
$scope.showAggregate = function() {
```

alert($scope.gridApi.grid.columns[5].getAggregationValue());
};

Which event I should make use of to retrieve this value. I need this approach since I will have dynamically generated grids and for each grid I need to capture the aggregate. Could any one help me here?

Comment: For the first issue where I was not getting aggregateText - I had no other way but build the column definition object. I implemented that and removed the registerColumnsProcessor approach.

Comment: For the 2nd issue to get the aggregatevalue I basically handles the  gridApi.core.on.rowsRendered event and in the handler I did something like  var agg_col = gridApi.grid.getColumn(fieldname);
                    //This is most important and it recalculated the values internally. Without this we are not getting the values.
                    agg_col.updateAggregationValue();